# Fusion of matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I'm interested in possibly wide classification of fusions of **real** matrix properties. I'll start from the example.

Let's suppose that we have matrix $P$  which is a **projection** matrix and a **symmetrical** matrix at the same time. From the first property we have $P=P^2$, from the second  one $P=P^T$.  Now let's calculate expression $v^TPv$ for any vector $v$.

We have $v^TPv=v^TP^2v=v^TPPv =(v^TP^T)(Pv)=(Pv)^T(Pv)= \Vert{Pv}\Vert^2\geq{0}$

i.e. condition characteristic for **positive-semidefinite** matrix.
In this case fusion of two properties leads to the interesting property on his own, which has even a distinct name.

> **Question:**
>   what are the other known cases of fusions of matrix properties which lead to a property which is enough interesting to give it a new name ?  Are there other similar cases? Can they always (*probably not*) be easily proved as in the case above?

Maybe answer could be listed in the form $A+B{\rightarrow}C:xTP$, 
see example:
**projection + symmetry $\rightarrow$ positive-semidefinitness: $ETP^*$**

$^*$($ETP$=easy to prove - criterion for easy: it can be done in a single line,
in similar way
$MTP$ - medium difficulty to prove(2-4 lines),
 $DTP$ - difficult to prove (more than 4 lines)).

*Edit (after two days)

Does nobody have any idea ? The example listed by me is the solely example for theory of matrices and their properties? It would be interesting to have such a list  to see clearly connections which not always are visible at the first sight...*